# Ways to make my own video play back?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, media, game-engine

So I've been doing a lot of searching today, trying to figure out how to play videos inside of a JFrame. The reason I want this is because, I'm making a game, and want the option to add movie clips, like in most every good game, such as GW2, Medal of Honor, etc.

So, in my searches, I found JMF, but was completely unable to use it. It is sort of frustrating, but whatever. So, my question is this: Is there a way to play videos WITHOUT installing any other jar's, exe's, etc? For example, run a simple code such as `new JFrame();` sort of quick and easy? or is that not possible, but there is a way to do it long and complex?
I've also been looking at other stack overflow stuff, and none of it really fits what i want... If worst comes to worst, i'll just use Xuggler, but i'd rather not.

Also, based on this answer, I plan on making a game engine in the future, so this could be added to it, for additional value.

Thank you in advance :)

PLEASE NOTE: I am not looking for references to JMF, or anything else like that. I'm looking for things such as built in methods/classes to call, or long work arounds, that work pretty good and would be implementable in numerous environments.

**EDIT:** I was thinking of using JEditorPane, and embedding the video with html, but.... that hasnt been working for me... here's what i've tried there:

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
        jep.setEditable(false);   

//        jep.setContentType("text/html");
          jep.setText("<html><video id=\"sampleMovie\" src=\"C:\\users\\austin\\desktop\\test.mp4\" controls></video></html>");

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep);     
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test HTML");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        f.setVisible(true);
```

But this doesnt seem to be working... Please help!

Comment: While it is not quick and easy, you can use JavaFX, which, as far as I know, comes with every desktop JRE.

Comment: I suggest you try using JVLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMF seems to have been around [since 1997](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework). No wonder then that, as you said, most of the Java-based players out there rely on it.

So I decided to take a trip back in time using Google's search options and found a result from Feb 2001: a very simple [GNU-licensed MPEG-1 player](http://vsr.informatik.tu-chemnitz.de/~jan/MPEG/MPEG_Play.html) implemented from the ground up using just Java and C. How about that? The following capture is from the website:

[image: MPEG-1 player]

I know you emphasised you needed a solution with as little external code as possible. In this case, no additional libraries seem to be required but you have to do some compiling. Plus you're limited to MPEG-1. So, not exactly what you were looking for but perhaps worth a look.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @PulsePanda Hey! Glad to know it's been helpful. Thanks for accepting and the bounty.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a `File` name "file":

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
//....
//....
//....
try{
    mediaURL = file.toURI().toURL();
}
catch(Exception e){
}
if(mediaURL != null){
    JFrame mediaTest = new JFrame();
    MediaPanel m = new MediaPanel(mediaURL);
    mediatTest.add(m);
    mediaTest.setVisible(true);
}
```

Edited:

```
import javax.media.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class MediaPanel extend JPanel{
    public MediaPanel( URL mediaURL){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        try{
            Player mp = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL);
            Component video = mp.getVisualComponent();
            Component controls = mp.getControlPaneComponent();
            if(video != null){
                add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
            if(controls != null){
                add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is mediapanel coming from?

Comment: Player and Manager are in the javax.media package, which is part of JMF.  Which means this answer ignores the part of the question that asks for a solution that doesn't use JMF.